# Adding an Exception into try catch

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I have a question regarding the Script below the script checks multiple Mailservers against RBL Lists, the Problem is that some of the Lists (like hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com) have certain answers that do not mean that the IP is actually blacklisted.

So I want to add an Exception into the `try..catch` function that if hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com answers with 127.0.2.1 the Mailserver is not getting into `$blacklistedOn`.

The Script:

```
Param([string]$IP)

$statusAlive = "ScriptRes:Host is alive:"
$statusDead = "ScriptRes:No answer:"
$statusUnknown     = "ScriptRes:Unknown:"
$statusNotResolved = "ScriptRes:Unknown host:"
$statusOk          = "ScriptRes:Ok:"
$statusBad         = "ScriptRes:Bad:"
$statusBadContents = "ScriptRes:Bad contents:"

$reversedIP = ($IP -split '\.')[3..0] -join '.'

$blacklistServers = @(
  "dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net";
  "dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net";
  "dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net";
  "ix.dnsbl.manitu.net";
  "bl.spamcop.net";
  "bl.spamcannibal.org";
  "b.barracudacentral.org";
  "ips.backscatterer.org";
  "dnsbl.sorbs.net";
  "cbl.abuseat.org";
  "all.spamrats.com";
  "black.uribl.com";
  "multi.surbl.org";
  "multi.uribl.com";
  "truncate.gbudb.net";
  "bl.blocklist.de";
  "dnsbl.inps.de";
  "bl.mailspike.net";
  "bl.spameatingmonkey.net";
  "db.wpbl.info";
  "dnsbl.justspam.org";
  "hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com";
  "mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org";
  "psbl.surriel.com";
  "spam.dnsbl.anonmails.de";
  "ubl.unsubscore.com";
  "cblless.anti-spam.org.cn";
  "cblplus.anti-spam.org.cn";
  "spam.pedantic.org";
  "dev.null.dk";
  "blackholes.five-ten-sg.com";
  "spamsources.fabel.dk";
  "zen.spamhaus.org";
  "spamguard.leadmon.net";
  "dialups.visi.com";
  "dnsbl.kempt.net";
  "dnsbl.dronebl.org";
  "no-more-funn.moensted.dk";
  "relays.bl.kundenserver.de";
)

$blacklistedOn = @()

foreach ($server in $blacklistServers) {
    $IPServer = "$reversedIP.$server"

    try {
        $null = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($IPServer)
        $blacklistedOn += $server
    } catch { }
}

if ($blacklistedOn.Count -gt 0) {
    # The IP was blacklisted on one or more servers; send your email here.
    # $blacklistedOn is an array of the servers that returned positive results.
    Write-Host "$statusAlive"$blacklistedOn
} else {
    Write-Host "$statusDead"$blacklistedOn
}
```

Comment: what kind of javascript is this?

Comment: This looks like some sort of .NET language

Comment: Well that was my bad, its a Poweshell Script, just had some trouble with a JavaScript so I still had JavaScritp in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your script discards whatever is returned by your host lookup. To skip over an address if a particular response is returned you need to assign it to a variable and check that before actually adding the server to `$blacklistedOn`:

```
try {
    $addr = [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($IPServer)
    if (-not ($server -eq 'hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com' -and $addr.AddressList.IPAddressToString -contains '127.0.2.1')) {
      $blacklistedOn += $server
    }
} catch { }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, my PowerShell knowledge is sadly not that good.